# Trying to install drivers manually without admin pass

Tags: mac, driver

Hi I'm trying to install the drivers for xone on my Mackbook Pro running 10.9.5.
I don't have admin rights and it is in .pkg file form. Help?

Answer (score 5):

You will need the admin password to install the driver.

Xone comes with a kernel extension aka `kext` file. Kernel extensions are installed in `/System/Library/Extensions/`, only administrators can modify the contents of this folder.

Ask an admin if he is willing to do it for you :)

Comment: Actually, can't you boot from an external OSX drive with root access and install either the driver manually or even set the installation target to the other drive? OSX File access is based on user IDs, and OSX will map the IDs of the internal drive to the IDs of the booted system.